# Check a result for sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the sequence $(U\:n) \to l$ such that $l < 1$, then 
$\exists n_0. \forall n. n \ge n_0 \Rightarrow (U\:n) <= 1$

Can anyone tell me if this result is correct? And if correct give me indications about its proof.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Let $\epsilon=1-l>0.$ Since $u_n\to l,$ then there exist some $n_0$ such that....

Answer (score 1):

The definition of convergence says that for any $\epsilon>0$,

$$\exists n_0. \forall n>n_0. l-\epsilon<U_n<l+\epsilon$$

If we choose $\epsilon=1-l$ we easily prove what you want.